# Show Disks in Nautilus sidebar

Tags: partitioning, mount, nautilus, drive

On a fresh installation of Ubuntu 23.10, my other drives do not appear in "Files" sidebar. I would like my mounted drive to appear their like in Dolphin.

I made some research, but nothing worked. I checked the "Show in user interface" checkbox in GNOME Disks, tried to replace the mount option from `x-gvfs-show` to`comment=x-gvfs-show`, and my drives are mounted in /media/[username].

I know that I can bookmark the directories where the drive is mounted, but that's not really what I'm looking for, as they look like the usual directory in the sidebar. I would like a clear separation between the drives and the bookmark, or at least, an icon or something. I remember that GNOME Files has this functionality, but it does not work out of the box on Ubuntu, it seems.

[image: Files without the drive appearing]

EDIT: my /etc/fstab:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda5 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/37096d3f-8ae0-4bd7-80b0-416d8d487166 / ext4 defaults 0 1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/B426-4B00 /boot/efi vfat defaults 0 1
/swap.img   none    swap    sw  0   0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/bd9bcfa6-44c4-47a8-911f-48a4f86b489e /media/deewens/L-Fast auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/9643e8fd-42e3-4a6d-a62a-1e9656b4c4b0 /media/deewens/L-Storage auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Nautilus, removable drives are by default shown in the sidebar when they are connected, i.e., mounted and available. If some of your drives are not, then this reflects an issue with the drive. It is rather common for drives formatted with the Windows file system `ntfs` not to show up. These partitions sometimes are not "clean", i.e., not fully closed, and users commonly are not aware of that. The Ubuntu system will not automount partitions that are not clean.

To resolve such issue, connect the partition to MS Windows and check it there. Then properly disconnect it from the system, i.e. ejecting the drive using the icons. Such healthy and properly closed file system will automatically be mounted when connected to Ubuntu.

Comment: Sorry, I may have explained it wrong, but I was talking about internal drives. I have three drives, each of them are divided in two (one for Windows as NTFS, and one for Linux as ext4). The ex4 partition does not show up in the sidebar. Is it because of the NTFS partition on the same drive? I don't think Windows is "mounting" ext4 partition, right?

Comment: I edited my question with my /etc/fstab!